# Determine integrals $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathrm{d}\delta_{3}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathrm{d}\delta_{\pi}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the function $u:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty]$ given by
$$
u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}1_{[n,n+1]}(x)
$$
I have determined that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathbb{d}\lambda=\pi^{2}/6$ where $\lambda$ is a Lebesgue measure. I want to determine the integrals $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathrm{d}\delta_{3}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathrm{d}\delta_{\pi}$, where $\delta_{y}$ is a Dirac measure in point $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

What I did: first, we have 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathrm{d}\delta_{3}=u(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}1_{[n,n+1]}(3).
$$
Since $1_{[n,n+1]}(3)=1$ where $3\in[n,n+1]$ is satisfied if $n=\lbrace 2,3\rbrace \subset \mathbb{N}$. That is, $1_{[2,3]}(3)=1_{[3,4]}(3)=1$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}1_{[n,n+1]}(3)=\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{3^{2}}.
$$
Similarly
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\, \mathrm{d}\delta_{\pi}=u(\pi)=\frac{1}{3^{2}}.
$$
Are they correct?

Comment: Yes, they are all fine.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks you for your answer. I am thinking about the notation. Is it possible or correct to write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}1_{[n,n+1]}(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left (1_{[2,3]}(3)+1_{[3,4]}(3)  \right )=\frac{1}{2^{2}}1_{[2,3]}(3)+\frac{1}{3^{2}}1_{[3,4]}(3)?$$

Comment: np. I added a few more relevant tags.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please answer my first (edited) comment?

Comment: No, the intermediate step is false (It would evaluate to $\frac{\pi^2}3$). The LHS and RHS are fine, though.